# MYSQL search previous datetime with null check on content

Tags: mysql, datetime

MySQL newbie here.

My db.TableA is 7million+ line long.
The simplified structure is:

```
DateTime as datetime (primary key)
Value as float.
```

It looks like a lot of people here is asking for a query to extract a row where a datetime is just before/just after a given datetime.
The queries in this case are something like:

```
select * from `TableA` where `DateTime`<'2016-06-01 00:00:23' order by `DateTime` desc limit 1; 
select * from `TableA` where `DateTime`>'2016-06-01 00:00:23' order by `DateTime` limit 1;
```

They are both very fast, some milliseconds on my slow db server.

**Here begins the fun**

Alas I have a twist that makes everything far slower.
An external device writes the rows *even if Value is not available*.
That means my database is populated by lines like

```
DateTime                Value
------------------------------
'2015-05-04 12:34:56'   Null
```

**The problem**: I need to find the first row with datetime just before/after a given datetime **AND with Value not null**.

Just adding the new condition to the previous queries makes them incredibly slow (from some milliseconds to more than one minute):

```
select * from `TableA` where `DateTime`<'2016-06-01 00:00:23' and Value is not null order by `DateTime` desc limit 1;
```

I assume that without the null check all is fast because it is based on an indexed DateTime and when checking the null condition the table is analyzed completely.

Is there a faster way to to this better, adding also a limit for the search?

I would like to search:

- a previous row (DateTime < given datetime)
- with Value not null
- but only if it is less that 1000 rows before DateTime (in any case it would be useless for me to pick a row that is too old for my calculations).

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Is it faster if you select the 1,000 rows as a subquery then select the first row from the derived table that isn't null? I'm thinking something like ``SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE `DateTime` < '2016-06-01 00:00:23' ORDER BY `DateTime` DESC LIMIT 1000) tmp WHERE tmp.Value IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1``

Comment: Sorry Matt, but my comment on your post has gone. 
If you post as an answer I can vote it as a positive solution.

Comment: Did it work? Faster than what you already had?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the maximum 1,000 rows before the given datetime first in a subquery, sort them in reverse chronological order, then select the first row from those 1,000 which has a non-`NULL` value.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM TableA
    WHERE `DateTime` < '2016-06-01 00:00:23'
    ORDER BY `DateTime` DESC LIMIT 1000) tmp
WHERE tmp.Value IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1
```

This should be faster because you don't have to scan the whole table for non-`NULL` values, just the most recent 1,000. Presumably there is an index on `DateTime` to make the subquery selection quick.